# Can Nginx generate ETag from response content?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, nginx

I've got simple question, I think. Can I use nginx for generating etags based on response content?

I found http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#etag
But its work only with static files and after adding `etag: on;` I don't see etag in header.

My stack is PHP, Symfony3 and Nginx. I want to add Etag on every response from server so I think that nginx will be the best option.

Any ideas?

Comment: same question! do you find any solution?

Comment: @Ali.MD Yes, I added support for weak ETag in FOS package. And use it: 
https://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/configuration/headers.html